# C# one timer for multiple shapes

Tags: c#, timer

For a school project I need to make a small game where multiple Ellipses move.
The last one that gets made with my method to make multiple at the same time moves with the timer I make.

How do you make one timer for all the Ellipses.

```
class EnemyTeam
{

    private Ellipse enemy;
    private Canvas canvas;
    private double xChange = 50, yChange = 50;
    public DispatcherTimer enemyTimer;
    private char direction = '0';
    private Thickness enemyThickness;

    public EnemyTeam(Canvas canvas, double startPosition, SolidColorBrush playerBrush)
    {
        this.canvas = canvas;
        DrawTeam(canvas, 40, playerBrush);
        enemyTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100);
        enemyTimer.Start();
    }

    private void DrawBall(SolidColorBrush brush, Canvas canvas,double x,double y)
    {
        enemy = new Ellipse();
        enemy.Stroke = brush;
        enemy.Fill = brush;
        enemy.Height = 30;
        enemy.Width = 30;
        enemy.Margin = new Thickness(x,y, 0, 0);
        enemyTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
        enemyThickness = enemy.Margin;
        canvas.Children.Add(enemy);   
        enemyTimer.Tick += enemyTimer_Tick;
    }

    void enemyTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (enemyThickness.Left >= canvas.Width - 100)
        {
            GoDown();
            direction = '1';
        }

        if (enemyThickness.Left <= 0 + 20)
        {
            GoDown();
            direction = '0';
        }
        MoveTeam(enemy);
    }

    private void MoveTeam(Ellipse enemy)
    {
        enemyThickness = enemy.Margin;

        if (direction == '1')
        {
            enemyThickness.Left -= xChange;
        }

        if (direction == '0')
        {
            enemyThickness.Left += xChange;
        }

        enemy.Margin = enemyThickness;
    }

    private void GoDown()
    {
        enemyThickness.Top += yChange;
        enemy.Margin = enemyThickness;
    }
}
```

Comment: From where do you call DrawBall? Unless it is called from DrawTeam, your current code will not work.

Comment: Yes, DrawBall gets called from DrawTeam.

Answer (score 0):

Declare enemyTimer as a static field:

```
class EnemyTeam
{
    private static enemyTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
...
```

The keyword static will make the field shared for the class.

Comment: Also not working, why did you use TimeSpan instead of DispatcherTimer here?

Comment: Changed to DispatcherTimer.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of initializing and assigning event handler in `DrawBall` method, do that in constructor of `EnemyTeam` class. This is will give you on timer per `EnemyTeam` object.

Comment: Nope still not working, Thanks for your answer though!

Comment: There's still only one ball moving per timer tick event, specifically the last one created in the for loop I use for DrawTeam().

Comment: Can you update the question with code in GoDown and MoveTeam methods?

Answer (score 0):

You're making multiple timers and throwing them away.  See this line:

```
enemyTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
```

Every time you call that, you're making a new timer and throwing away the previous copy that `enemyTimer` held a reference to.  Because `enemyTimer.Start()` is called after `DrawTeam`, it's called only on the last-created timer.  None of the other timers get started.

But even if the other timers got started, you'd still only see one Ellipse move, because in `enemyTimer_Tick` you only ever make changes to `enemy`, which is a class member variable that points to the last Ellipse created.

I would suggest that you only use one timer, that you save all the Ellipses you create in a list for later use, and that in `enemyTimer_Tick` you update all of those Ellipses by iterating through the list.

**EDIT**: Here is a copy of your code, reworked a bit to show you what I mean.  I don't really understand what you're trying to do with MoveTeam and the enemyThickness variable, so I didn't mess with that stuff.  That is to say, this isn't a complete working solution, just an example of the changes I'm suggesting.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

class EnemyTeam
{

    private List<Ellipse> enemies = new List<Ellipse>();
    private Canvas canvas;
    private double xChange = 50, yChange = 50;
    public DispatcherTimer enemyTimer;
    private char direction = '0';
    private Thickness enemyThickness;

    public EnemyTeam(Canvas canvas, double startPosition, SolidColorBrush playerBrush)
    {
        this.canvas = canvas;
        DrawTeam(canvas, 40, playerBrush);
        enemyTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
        enemyTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100);
        enemyTimer.Tick += enemyTimer_Tick;
        enemyTimer.Start();
    }

    private void DrawBall(SolidColorBrush brush, Canvas canvas,double x,double y)
    {
        enemy = new Ellipse();
        enemy.Stroke = brush;
        enemy.Fill = brush;
        enemy.Height = 30;
        enemy.Width = 30;
        enemy.Margin = new Thickness(x,y, 0, 0);
        enemyThickness = enemy.Margin; // what is this supposed to do?
        canvas.Children.Add(enemy);
        enemies.Add(enemy);
    }

    void enemyTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Ellipse enemy in enemies)
        {
            if (enemyThickness.Left >= canvas.Width - 100)
            {
                GoDown();
                direction = '1';
            }

            if (enemyThickness.Left <= 0 + 20)
            {
                GoDown();
                direction = '0';
            }
            MoveTeam(enemy);
        }
    }

    private void MoveTeam(Ellipse enemy)
    {
        enemyThickness = enemy.Margin;

        if (direction == '1')
        {
            enemyThickness.Left -= xChange;
        }

        if (direction == '0')
        {
            enemyThickness.Left += xChange;
        }

        enemy.Margin = enemyThickness;
    }

    private void GoDown()
    {
        enemyThickness.Top += yChange;
        enemy.Margin = enemyThickness;
    }
}
```

Comment: Would you be so gentle to give me some sample code not much but just a starter as I don't fully understand the method you're explaining

Comment: I've added a tweaked version of your code that may help.

Comment: All Ellipse objects move now just have to tweak the code a bit to make them move how they're supposed to do. and the enemyThickness is used because we didn't see another way of updating margins yet, no matter what I did I always got an error working with margin alone. I really appreciate your help! Trying to make a space invaders like game btw.